# Algorithm to check if there is an inducing path between two nodes - constructing maximal ancestral graph (MAG) given a DAG

Tags: causality, graphical-model, graph-theory, causal-diagram

In causal inference, one generally learns a Markov equivalence class of causal graphs when trying to reconstruct causal structure from data. This is known as a maximal ancestral graph (MAG).

I am wondering if there is an algorithm, or study/paper that shows how to construct a MAG given a DAG. In this [study](https://www.jmlr.org/papers/volume9/zhang08a/zhang08a.pdf), the following two steps are enumerated:

1. for each pair of variables A,B $\in$ O, A and B are adjacent in $M_G$ if and only if there is an inducing path between them relative to L in G;
2. for each pair of adjacent variables A,B in $M_G$, orient the edge as A → B in $M_G$ if A is an ancestor of B in G; orient it as A←B in $M_G$ if B is an ancestor of A in G; orient it as A<->B in $M_G$ otherwise.

Step 2 is straightforward to check in a graph, but what would be a suitable algorithm for determining if there is an inducing path between A and B relative to L? Naively, you could check all paths between A and B, but that seems rather inefficient for any graphs with 5-10 nodes.

Comment: Alas, I am not at all sure there is anyone on Stats.SE except Judea Pearl himself who could answer this question. MAGs are an extremely advanced topic in the New Causal Revolution. See this question (no answers, unfortunately): https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/567957/whats-the-mag-of-this-underlying-dag